# Is there an easy way to remove all data from MongoDB collection in C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to make a unique method for deleting all data from MongoDB collection in C#.

Before I called only ***RemoveAll()*** method and it worked. But now as it has only ***DeleteOne()*** i ***DeleteMany()*** methods where I should put filter, but as this method should be unique for all collections, I am not sure how to make filter to remove all data from collection without deleting collection.

For Collection it is not specified which one, it should go as a parameter to the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an empty `BsonDocument` to delete all the documents from the collection:

```cs
collection.DeleteMany(new BsonDocument());
```